# Android change Fragment in FragmentActivity when asynctask run

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Here is the context, I've a `FragmentActivity` with `Fragment` inside.

The FragmentActivity contains *tabInfo* and when the user click on it, I change the Fragment.

But when the user come on the FragmentActivity, I launch a `asynctask` for load pictures. **And I can't changed tab until the asynctask is finished...**

Comment: can you provide some of your code, because it seams like your loading pictures on UiThread

Answer (score 1):

You can use the publishProgress from inside doInBackground and override onProgressUpdate to display something into UI thread.

Inside doInBackground you can't touch your views, also the process is termitent in the thread so all your change fragment actions will be executed when its done.

Comment: Ok but why I can't switch tab until the webservice respond?

Comment: added. try the publishProgress approach, it will run out of the background thread